# Получить значение тэга в событии

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть блок с ссылками

```
 <a :href="'/catalog/category/edit?id=123'" class="label font-weight-bold">Тут имя ссылки</a>
```

Блок заполняется из другого компонента:

```
<div class="card-body" v-on:click.prevent="select($event)" >
      <tree :tree-data="tree "></tree>
</div>
```

Я могу получать значения атрибутов

```
   select: function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.getAttribute('href'));
    },
```

Как мне получить `"Тут имя ссылки"` значение тэга `<a>`?

Comment: С помощью `ref` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения контента через `event`, надо у `target` обратиться к полю `text`

```
select: function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.text);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]